# XML parsing error: not well-formed (invalid token) for <id> element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

When building an atom feed, I have encountered the following error from the [W3C validation service](https://validator.w3.org/feed/):

This feed does not validate.

line 12, column 106: XML parsing error: :12:106: not well-formed (invalid token) [help]

```
... ack/click?u=2bfa40e46beb7840286deead5&id=fe176e8c71&e=317c895d8d</id>
                                             ^
```

The feed contains my email messages and it is build using google app script. The cited line is about a link of a very annoying tracking system in a newletter I subscribed.

I hate such things. Anyway, I have to understand why the error arises to have my feed working.

The complete line in my feed is as following (I only removed the domain name not to advertise such a tracking system).

```
       <id>https://omissis.invalid/track/click?u=2bfa40e46beb7840286deead5&id=fe176e8c71&e=317c895d8d</id>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. You need to use the `&amp;` entity for each ampersand symbol.

```
<id>https://omissis.invalid/track/click?u=2bfa40e46beb7840286deead5&amp;id=fe176e8c71&amp;e=317c895d8d</id>
```